# AUNode CAShow Output

Tags: ios, core-audio

I have two different iOS projects that create an AUGraph that has 1 Multichannel Mixer and 1 Remote IO Audio Units.

In one project, when I print the output of the AUGraph using `CAShow()` I get the following:

```
node 1: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x7e2c910 O I
node 2: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl', instance 0x7e33c00 O I
```

However in the other project I get this:

```
node 1: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x7a5a750 O  
node 2: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl', instance 0x7a5e710 O
```

As you can see, the 1st project has both "O" and "I" whereas the second only has "O".

Two questions:

1. What do those letters refer to? I can't find any documentation of
   them.
2. Any ideas what might account for "I" not showing up in the 2nd
   project? As best I can tell I'm creating the AUGraph exactly the
   same in both projects.

At first I thought it indicated whether input is enabled on the remote IO unit, however I'm definitely enabling it in both projects so that doesn't explain it.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult to tell without seeing the code in play, but I believe those are referring to "Opened" and "Initialized".